# Retrieve Amazon Reviews user emails through API

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, api

I can't find a API service to

1. retrieve amazon reviews data
2. **get specifically the user emails** (in order to not duplicate further survey emails)

Can I achieve this without using an external scraper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible, unfortunately. [The Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/assoc_credentials/home) is probably as close as you will get. The user emails are not exposed.

Comment: I thought it wasn't possible, but I had to check. Thanks Cassidy